# How can i make a call on wildcard numbers in my android application?

Tags: android, call, ocr

I am making an application in with user scan card number (14-digit) number thru camera then make a call. The call require a wildcard character "#" at the end of the number, but my app don`t add that character. What should I do?

I am using this

```
String cardNumber = textValue.getText().toString().trim();
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);

if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, Integer.parseInt("123"));
}
else {
     startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL).setData(Uri.parse("tel:*123*"+cardNumber+"#")));
}
```

Comment: what number are you getting in dial screen ?

Comment: Are you getting card number after scaning exactly??

Comment: yes i am getting cardNumber exactly same...but when i dial a number it dont add # at the end of my number...

Comment: Great  I have been  trying to get number after scaning a card programatically. Could you suggest me which approach i can get result.thanks in andvance..

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:*123*"+cardNumber+ Uri.encode("#"))));               try this hoping it works:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code for your issue :

```
 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
 callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ Uri.encode("*123#")));
 startActivity(callIntent);
```

or

add value at runtime

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
String cardnm = "8585"; // cardname value......
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode("*123*" + cardnm + "#")));
startActivity(callIntent);
```